# window function to python pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Below is a sql code based on window functions which is working fine:

```
select sum(sales) over (partition by category1, category2
order by year, month
rows between 7 preceding and current row) as new_col
from table_1;
```

Aim is to convert this sql code to python script, I've an idea of a groupby in pandas, but not sure how to convert window functions to pandas way of code and need help with that, thanks

Comment: `.groupby(...).rolling(...)`?

Comment: Appreciate if you could share the equivalent code for it, thanks @BigBen

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rolling.html ?

Comment: It's probably going to look something like `df["new_col"] = df.groupby(["category1", "category2"])["sales"].rolling(7).sum()` Some effort may be needed by you to port this further to account for any edge cases, ordering, or differences between the two platforms.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill, in the shared code, year and month columns are missing, could you put that up as an answer pls?

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, for sharing the doc reference, can you also help with where to accommodate year & month for order by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have an example of data so writing code blind *(after edit)*:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'category1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'category2': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X'],
    'year': [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023],
    'month': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    'sales': [100, 150, 110, 120, 130, 140, 155, 160, 125, 135]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.sort_values(by=['category1', 'category2', 'year', 'month'], inplace=True)
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(['category1', 'category2'])['sales'] \
                 .rolling(window=8, min_periods=1).sum().reset_index(drop=True).values
```

My *edited* logics:

1. We first sort the entire dataframe by the columns 'category1', 'category2', 'year', and 'month'.
2. We then compute the rolling sum on the sorted dataframe, grouped by 'category1' and 'category2'.
3. By using `reset_index(drop=True).values`, we transform the series into an array that can be directly assigned to the `new_col` of the original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @Iskander14yo, but this gives a result of 2 columns, so 'result' cannot be assigned to dataframe df, got any other way to solve this?

Comment: @RavenSmith edited post, try now please

Comment: Thanks @Iskander14yo, is there any changes I've to make if I need `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`